# Grails Pagination: how to use pagination

Tags: grails, datatables, pagination

I have a list of orders (20000 records),the loading is very slow, 
I'm looking a way to load just the first ten and then activate the pagination

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work about what you tried? This question is far too general to give a good answer.

Comment: my list work's but he's very slow, i want to make it faster, 
I need now to load just the ten first elements, then i used the pagination to load the rest (sorry with my english)

Comment: Rahul's answer below describes how to configure a GSP with pagination controls.  Your question doesn't indicate that you are even using GSP.  Is his answer what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

You have provided very little information so it is difficult to say what the best solution is.

> I'm looking a way to load just the first ten and then activate the
>   pagination

I don't know what you mean by "activate the pagination".

Assuming you are using GORM, a way to retrieve the first 10 records could be something like this...

```
YourDomainClass.list(offset:0, max: 10)
```

To retrieve the next 10...

```
YourDomainClass.list(offset: 10, max: 10)
```

etc...

You could find out the total number of records with something like `YourDomainClass.count()` and use that to invoke the `.list(...)` method over and over to retrieve all of the records, 10 at a time.

I hope that helps.

Comment: @MamoudouNdiaye why would you prefer `Order.createCriteria().list(max: 10, offset: 0){}` over `Order.list(max: 10, offset: 0)`?  With the former you are allocating a `Closure` which doesn't do anything and involving pieces of the framework that aren't contributing anything but are being engaged anyway.

Comment: in fact , i wanted just to make a server side pagination. i tried this :                
  def getListOrder() {
        def employeList = Order.createCriteria().list(max: 10, offset: 0) {
            if (params.numero && !"".equals(params.numero)) {
                ilike("numero", "%${params.numero}%")
            }        
            }
        def totalRows = employeList.totalCount
               def collection  = employeList.collect{
                    [ numero : it.numero  ]   }
        def result = [total: totalRows, rows: collection]
        render result as JSON
    }

Answer (score 0):

Refer this

**domain class:**

```
class DataEntry{
    String sendersName
}
```

**controller:**

```
class TransactionsController {
    def list() {
        [data: DataEntry.list(params), dataEntryCount: DataEntry.count()]
    }
}
```

**Paginate code:**

```
<g:paginate controller="transactions" action="list" total="${dataEntryCount}" />
```

**OR**

```
<g:paginate next="Forward" prev="Back"
            maxsteps="0" controller="transactions"
            action="list" total="${dataEntryCount}" />
```

Please refer [documentation](http://docs.grails.org/3.1.1/ref/Tags/paginate.html) for more details

Comment: In a comment that Mamoudou left on another answer here, they indicated that they are not using GSP.